# How to use cross_val_predict to predict probabilities for a new dataset?

Tags: scikit-learn

I am using sklearn's cross_val_predict for training like so:

```
  myprobs_train = cross_val_predict(LogisticRegression(),X = x_old, y=y_old, method='predict_proba', cv=10)
```

I am happy with the returned probabilities, and would like now to score up a brand-new dataset.  I tried:

```
  myprobs_test = cross_val_predict(LogisticRegression(), X =x_new, y= None, method='predict_proba',cv=10)
```

but this did not work, it's complaining about y having zero shape.   Does it mean there's no way to apply the trained and cross-validated model from cross_val_predict on new data?  Or am I just using it wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Yep, not surprised it errored because you didn't include any y values in your second run. Do you want to do some out of sample predictions? cross_val_predict might not be the best for that as it doesn't allow you to fit and predict in two steps

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking at a wrong method. Cross validation methods do not return a trained model; they return values that evaluate the performance of a model (logistic regression in your case). Your goal is to fit some data and then generate prediction for new data. The relevant methods are [fit](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.fit) and [predict](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.predict) of the [LogisticRegression class](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html). Here is the basic structure:

```
logreg = linear_model.LogisticRegression()
logreg.fit(x_old, y_old)
predictions = logreg.predict(x_new)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same concern as @user3490622. If we can only use cross_val_predict on training and testing sets, why y (target) is None as the default value? ([sklearn page](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_predict.html))

To partially achieve the desired results of multiple predicted probability, one could use the fit then predict approach repeatedly to mimic the cross-validation.